# Overwiritng specific folders rentention policies in purview

Tags: office365, retention

We currently have a retention policy in place that deletes any emails older than 7 years in a specific mailbox. We want to change that policy to 4 years instead of 7 years. My plan is to edit the current policy and make the change. Now, the issue is that we still need to keep emails older than 7 years in two specific folders in the mailbox.

After doing some research, it seems like a retention tag might be what I need to use. My question is, if I change the policy and then apply the retention tag, will that tag overwrite the policy and keep emails less than 7 years old?

Comment: Yes, you can use retention tags to overwrite the default retention policy for specific folders. You can modify your current retention policy to delete emails older than 4 years then create a new retention tag with a retention period of 7 years which you will apply to the two specific folders. This way, the new policy will delete emails older than 4 years, but the two folders with the new retention tag will keep emails for 7 years. Please see this documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/security-and-compliance/messaging-records-management/retention-tags-and-policies